# How to get the id value of the selected row in a table created by ASP.Net Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-table

I've having a hard time getting the value of the id of the selected row in a table that was written using Razor.

I've tried this code:

```
@model IEnumerable<Payout.Models.user>


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.username)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.email)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.username)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email)
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success submit" onclick="DeleteUser(item.userid)">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

But this code doesn't work and I just need to get the `userid` of the row where the button delete is clicked. The `userid` is not shown on the table but supplied in the model. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just missing the razor `@` bang.

```
<td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success submit" onclick="DeleteUser(@item.userid)">Delete</button>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you for this :) I don't really think I've just miss out the `@` symbol.